# react-app-rewired production build failed This probably means the system ran out of memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, circleci, production, react-app-rewired

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=4001 react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider'; react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=8096 build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired --env=jsdom"
  },
```

I am using `react-app-rewired` for building my react application.
Below is my `config-overrides.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const {override, addLessLoader} = require('customize-cra')

const overrideProcessEnv = value => config => {
  config.resolve.modules = [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  ].concat(config.resolve.modules);
  return config;
};

module.exports = override(
  addLessLoader({
    javascriptEnabled: true,
  }),
  overrideProcessEnv({
    VERSION: JSON.stringify(require('./package.json').version),
  })
);
```

While I build in local system it works, it doesn't work in prod server.
`node` version is latest.
Logs:-

```
yarn install v1.22.15
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning react-scripts > @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin > native-url > querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning react-scripts > @svgr/webpack > @svgr/plugin-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > webpack-log > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
warning react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > babel-jest > @jest/transform > jest-haste-map > sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
warning react-scripts > optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin > cssnano > cssnano-preset-default > postcss-svgo > svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
warning react-scripts > postcss-preset-env > postcss-color-gray > postcss-values-parser > flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > strip-comments > babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning " > less-loader@5.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "less@^2.3.1 || ^3.0.0".
warning " > less-loader@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning " > react-custom-scrollbars@4.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning " > react-custom-scrollbars@4.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.21.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 40.24s.

> platform_ui@2.0.0 build
> export NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider'; react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=8096 build

Creating an optimized production build...
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.

Exited with code exit status 1
```